# How to use php variable in text in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a file with urls to websites:

```
$var1 = www.google1.com/asdfsd
$var2 = www.google2.com/fdfff
```

And now I want to use these variables in text in posts, for example:

```
any text <a href="<?php $var1 ?>">my sample link</a>
```

I cannot use wordpress plugins to insert php in post. 
How can I include file with my variables to wordpress and then use these variables in text ?

Comment: You must use http:// or https:// before you links i.e. http://www.google1.com/asdfsd / http://www.google2.com/fdfff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to look at using [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), for example in your themes functions.php file you can do this:

```
add_shortcode('var1', function($atts) {
   return 'www.google1.com/asdfsd';
}

add_shortcode('var2', function($atts) {
   return 'www.google1.com/fdfff';
}
```

Then in your text view you can do the below:

```
any text <a href="[var1]">my sample link</a>
```

Alternatively, you could setup one shortcode for all links and pass in a parameter to the shortcode which could be done like so:

```
add_shortcode('link', function($atts) {
   switch($atts['type']):
      case 1: return 'www.google1.com/asdfsd'; break;
      case 2: return 'www.google1.com/fdfff'; break;
      default: return '';
   endswitch;
}
```

And include in your pages like so:

```
any text <a href="[link type='2']">my sample link</a>
```